# Why is my menu page not being displayed?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development

Hi i created a custom plugin and I want to add a menu page but is not being displayed. I followed the documentation but it is not working.

class-training_csv_importer-admin.php:

```
public function register_menu()
    {
        $this->public_screen_hook_suffix = add_menu_page(
            __('CSV Post Importer', 'training-csv-importer'),
            __('CSV Post Importer', 'training-csv-importer'),
            'manage_options',
            'training-csv-display_options_page',
            [$this, 'display_options_page'],
            'dashicons-media-spreadsheet',
            3
        );
    }
```

Comment: how/when is your class and this function being called? Have you confirmed the `add_menu_page` code actually runs?

Comment: @TomJNowell how can i check that?

Comment: Did you write this code? Where/How are you executing/running/calling `register_menu`? You haven't shared very much code so this isn't something I could read and figure out on my own

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.